# Deleting an object from Redis not working C#

Tags: c#, redis

I am trying to delete an object from Redis and the following code works

```
var items = redisClient.As<Item>();
var test1 = new Item { ItemNumber = 1000, Title = "This is a Title" };
var test2 = new Item { ItemNumber = 1001, Title = "A Unique Title"};

items.Store(test1);
items.Store(test2);
items.Delete(test2);
```

However when I run the following code it is not work.

```
public void DeleteInterval(Interval interval)
{
   var items = redis.As<Interval>();
   items.Delete(interval);
}
```

How does redis delete work on the first sample code and not the second?

using monitor I found the problem but don't know how to solve it but I get the following information.

First Code:

```
"SADD" "ids.Item" "54986669"
"DEL" "urn:item:54986669"
```

Second Code:

```
"SADD" "ids.Interval" "40807399"
"MGET" "urn:interval:40807399"
"DEL" "urn:interval:13133063"
"SREM" "ids.Interval" "13133063"
```

Is there a way to control the ID's in redis?

Comment: are you sure you getting the items you're expecting in the DeleteInterval ?

Comment: Yes the object that I am receiving is exactly what I am expecting.

Comment: Use the MONITOR command on Redis to see exactly what commands are received. It will help you to pinpoint the problem. http://redis.io/commands/MONITOR

Comment: I have updated my question and I am now a little confused why the id's would be different.